# Azure Devops pipelines Deploying a scheduled task using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline with a PowerShell task, which when triggered, successfully creates and configures a Windows Scheduled Task on my Windows Server.

The configuration sets the task to run using an AD Service account, 'Run whether the user is logged on or not' & 'Run with the highest privileges'.

When I try to run this task however, I get the message "The user account does not have permission to run this task."

If I manually create a scheduled task using all the same details, it runs without issue.

I've seen other threads about going into the C:\Windows\System32\Tasks folder, and change the security to update the Owner, but I still get the same result.

Has anyone had any luck setting a Scheduled task up via PowerShell script, and/or what the resolution to the permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering around, I found that the Azure DevOps agent was set up using the default SYSTEM credentials.

I created a new ADO Agent that runs as an admin Service account, and when the Scheduled task was deployed, it ran without issue.